# split view controller in a custom container controller?

Tags: ios5, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am wondering if it is possible to present a splitviewcontroller within a custom container controller (or a tabbar controller)? I have seen from this [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html) and other post:

> A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you
>   create. In other words, you must always install the view from a
>   UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s
>   window. [...] Split view controllers cannot be presented modally.

I have a splash screen in my app that will lead me to this container controller which I would like to contain a splitview controller. Is it just impossible according to Apple Programming guide or is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible, but you run the risk of violating Apple UX guidelines. 
What you can do is embed a splitview controller as a child viewcontroller of an blank UIViewController instance, and then present that viewcontroller instead of presenting the UISplitViewController directly.